# Highcharts Tooltip At Column Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am working on this example: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo

When I hover to some color pie chart, i.e. blue the tooltip is

```
Jane: 13 fruits
```

However when I hover to first colum (blue one at apples) tooltip is:

```
Apples: 3
```

Its Jane's apples. So how can I change it to:

```
Jane : 3 apples
```

Any ideas?

**PS**:

The tooltip formatter used at example is:

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            var s;
            if (this.point.name) { // the pie chart
                s = ''+
                    this.point.name +': '+ this.y +' fruits';
            } else {
                s = ''+
                    this.x  +': '+ this.y;
            }
            return s;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the `series` data using `this.series.someAttr`.
So, do the following:

```
formatter: function() {
    var s;
    if (this.point.name) { // the pie chart
        s = this.point.name +' '+ this.y +' fruits';
    } else {
        s = this.series.name + ' : ' +
            this.x  +': '+ this.y;
    }
    return s;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rKBjq/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            var s;
            if (this.point.name) { // the pie chart
                s = ''+
                    this.point.name +': '+ this.y +' fruits';
            } else {
                s = ''+
                    this.series.name  +': '+ this.y+' '+this.x;
            }
            return s;
        }
    }
```